# How do I create a Jenkins Build Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have downloaded Jenkins' [Build Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin).

The docs state:

> Create a view of the new type Build Pipeline View.
>
> You will then be redirected directly to the configuration page.

I just don't see the right button to create a new pipeline. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your quotation a Build Pipeline is not of a job kind: it is a *view*. You have to use "Create view" which is rendered as a plus sign placed in right-most tab. Or you can use direct link: `http://jenkins.example.com/newView`. There you will be able to select "Build Pipeline View" and proceed to its configuration page.

Comment: I only have List View and My View options. Maybe they removed it in the new version.

Answer (score 2):

The Build Pipeline plugin allows you to create views of the downstream and upstream relations between your jobs (and also add manual steps in-between them). To create the pipeline you should first define these relations by using post-build triggers or the `Build after other projects are built` option, for example.

Then, you create the view as izzekil described in his answer and get a pipeline similar to the one below:

[image: pipeline-example]

Answer (score 1):

I have Jenkins v 1.6 and I had it under the + button here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @izzekil's useful link above to the *newView* page, you might also be able to make sure of the *Views* tab if you have it on the Jenkins home page.

[image]